# How to write common implementation of __str__ method for all my models in Django?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, abstract

I want all my models to override `__str__` method in similar fashion:

```
class MyModel1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __init__(self):
        self.to_show = 'name'

    def _show(self):
        if hasattr(self,self.to_show):
            return str(getattr(self, self.to_show))
        else:
            return str(getattr(self, 'id'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self._show()

class MyModel2AndSoOn(models.Model):
    another_param = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # same implementation of `__str__` but with another_param
```

I do not want to repeat the same code for all my models so I tried inheritance:

```
class ShowModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __init__(self):
        self.to_show = 'name'

    def _show(self):
        if hasattr(self,self.to_show):
            return str(getattr(self, self.to_show))
        else:
            return str(getattr(self, 'id'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self._show()

class MyModel1(ShowModel):
    another_param = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MyModel2(ShowModel):
    another_param = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

but it messes with `id` of `MyModel1` and `MyModel2` by replacing `id` with a pointer to `ShowModel`. How to write common implementation of `__str__` method for my models without inheritance or how to prevent treating `ShowModel` class as a Django model?

**Upd:** I used `abstract` model as alecxe suggested but it ended with an error message:

```
in _show
    return str(getattr(self, self.to_show))
File "/path/to/my/project/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 188, in __str__
model = self.model
AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

**Upd** Everything works fine if I assign value to the `name` field of my model object. Whole solution:

```
class ShowModel(object):
    to_show = 'name'

    def _show(self):
            if hasattr(self,self.to_show):
                return str(getattr(self, self.to_show))
            elif hasattr(self,'id'):
                return str(getattr(self, 'id'))
            else:
                return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
         return self._show()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyModel1(ShowModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    to_show = 'name'

class MyModel2(ShowModel):
    another_param = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    to_show = 'another_param'
```

in test case:

```
ua = MyModel1()
ua.name = 'hi'
print(ua)
#prints hi

ub = MyModel2()
ub.another_param = 'hi again'
print(ub)
#prints hi again
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an [*`abstract` model*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

```
class ShowModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __init__(self):
        self.to_show = 'name'

    def _show(self):
        if hasattr(self, "to_show"):
            return str(getattr(self, "to_show"))
        else:
            return str(getattr(self, 'id'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self._show()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And, as for your follow-up question and thanks to @itzmeontv, you should replace `self.to_show` with "to_show" when calling `hasattr()` and `getattr()`.

Comment: That was an unexpectedly simple answer! But it gave the following error: Upd question.

Comment: None of my classes has attribute `show`. If you ment `to_show` then `hasattr(self, 'to_show')` checks whether `MyModel1` or `ShowModel` has `to_show` attribute but what I want to check is whether `MyModel` or `ShowModel` have value of `to_show` i.e. `name` attribute

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко ah, my bad, updated accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: It turned out that when I try to register MyModel in admin I get an error `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко please consider making a separate question for this separate problem. This way more people may potentially help and benefit! Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Have already made and deleted because I just accidentally had  inherited `ShowModel` from `object` instead of `models.Model` in my code.